# Errors while trying to perform Single Node Cloud Foundry VCAP Deployment

Tags: installation, cloud-foundry

I am attempting to install the `Cloud Foundry VCAP` as a single node on an `Ubutnu 10.04.4 VM` using the instructions provided [here](http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20407923-single-multi-node-vcap-deployment-using-dev-setup). I am logged in as a root.

I complete the Common tasks without problem, but when I get to attempting Option 2 under Single Node Deployment, where I execute the script `bin/vcap_dev_setup` I do not get the expected results. First, it does not promt me for the sudo password (perhaps since I am logged in as root?) and then it seems to run fine until it gets to a file it tries to download but can't...

```
root@cloudlg187220:~/cloudfoundry/vcap/dev_setup/bin# ./vcap_dev_setup
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release.gpg
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US                                  
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/restricted Translation-en_US                             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe Translation-en_US                               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/multiverse Translation-en_US                             
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release.gpg [198B]                                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Translation-en_US                               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/restricted Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/universe Translation-en_US                       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid Release                                                          
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates Release [58.3kB]                                       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release.gpg                             
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net/swift-core/ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main Translation-en_US
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release.gpg [198B]         
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid Release                             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/main Sources                  
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/restricted Sources            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/universe Sources              
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security Release [57.3kB]     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Packages                   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid/multiverse Sources                    
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Packages [663kB]       
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages                                    
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages                                    
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net lucid/main Packages              
  404  Not Found
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Packages [4,624B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/main Sources [233kB]
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Packages [474kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/restricted Sources [2,196B]       
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Packages [317kB]         
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/universe Sources [106kB]          
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Packages [11.5kB]      
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com lucid-updates/multiverse Sources [5,823B]     
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Packages [2,829B]           
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/main Sources [134kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/restricted Sources [1,267B]
Get:17 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Packages [168kB]
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/universe Sources [43.8kB]
Get:19 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Packages [5,343B]
Get:20 http://security.ubuntu.com lucid-security/multiverse Sources [2,337B]
Fetched 2,290kB in 4s (553kB/s)                
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/swift-core/ppa/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Every reference to this error I find online has no answer. Does anyone have an idea or suggestion? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article you want to use to install vcap on a single VM/Machine is at the following:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/vcap/tree/master/dev_setup

The link you provided is out of date